# Shapes blending incorrectly in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a smaller rectangle inside a larger one, like this:

[image]

When I try to blend them by selecting the blend tool, clicking on the smaller, lighter rectangle, then clicking on the larger, darker rectangle, this is the result:

[image]

Why didn't they blend smoothly together? Any idea what is causing this to happen?